# Python Tensorflow: cast placeholder to string

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, casting

In python, I am trying to cast a Tensorflow placehoder of type `tf.float32` to `tf.string`. The converse is possible through [`tf.to_float()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/casting), however there is no `to_string`...

Trying:

```
resample_multiplier_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [], name='resample_multiplier')
name_ = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
resample_multiplier_str_ = tf.cast(resample_multiplier_,tf.string) + name_
```

gives me (when I try to run the session):

> UnimplementedError: Cast float to string is not supported

How could I convert a Tensorflow placehoder of type `tf.float32`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func):

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
to_str_op = tf.py_func(lambda val: str(val), [x], tf.string)
print(to_str_op.dtype)  # <dtype: 'string'>
```